# Adjective Declension after ein bisschen, ein wenig, ein paar

Tags: adjective-ending, determiners

If we use ein bisschen, ein wenig, ein paar as a determiner then can I assume that the declension of adjective before noun is in a mix declension because of indefinite article ein? I write the following example with adjective **rot** please check if it is correct or not.

> eine bisschen **rote** Schokolade

Answer (score 3):

Examples such as the following show that if *ein wenig* modifies a noun, *ein* is uninflected and the adjective accordingly carries strong inflection.

> mit ein wenig gesund**em** Menschenverstand
> *with a little bit of common sense*

Note that *ein wenig* can also modify an adjective. This can lead to constructions beginning with *ein ein* or *der ein*.

> **ein** ein wenig verwundert**er** **Gast**
> *a guest that is a little bit puzzled*
>
> **der** ein wenig verrückt**e** **Ritter**
> *the knight that is a little bit crazy*

While *ein wenig* and *ein bißchen* stand with singular mass nouns, *ein paar* stands with plural nouns. Note that again *ein* is uninflected and the adjective carries strong inflection.

> ein paar schwierig**e** Entscheidungen
> *a few difficult decisions*

Of course, *ein Paar* with a capital P means *a pair* and is different, as the inflected article shows (also compare *Quentchen*).

> mit **einem Paar** Handschuhe
> *with a pair of gloves*
>
> mit **einem Quentchen** Glück
> *with a modicum of luck*

Finally, in colloquial speech, you can find examples such as the following, where an inflected form of the definite article is combined with *bißchen* or *paar*.

> wegen d**em** bißchen Geld, wegen d**en** paar Euro

Answer (score 2):

With *ein(e)*, *[Bb]isschen*, *rot* and *Schokolade* you can express a number of things that can vary widely in meaning:

1. You want to express there is a small bit of chocolate, you would use

   > Ein bisschen rote Schokolade

   In this example, "Schokolade" has no article (that works because "Schokolade" can go as a material designation, like "Milch" or "Wasser" which can go without an article), the "ein" belongs to "bisschen".

   Here, *bisschen* modifies the noun, denoting there is a bit of it.
2. You want to express the chocolate is *slightly red*, thus modify not the noun, but rather the adjective, you need to double the article ("ein bisschen" cannot go without an article, and "Schokolade" needs one, too because you mean a specific piece of chocolate - the slightly red one, not the material):

   > Eine ein bisschen rote Schokolade
3. If you modify the capitalization, you can modify "Bisschen" to a noun (literally meaning "a small bite") and form

   > Ein Bisschen rote Schokolade

   like in "ein Glas kaltes Wasser"

   This would not be used commonly, as it could only go for a literal bite of chocolate that someone bites off and spits out.

But after all: who would want red chocolate, anyway?

Answer (score -3):

Construct the structure as if *bißchen* wouldn't exist. So,

> eine rote Schokolade

is what you want. Here we have the basic-level weak declination (*eine bißchen Schokolade*, *ein großer Tisch*, *eine kleine Pause*, and so on).

**Bißchen** is not a part of this construction, *you can use them as if it wouldn't exist.*

Comment: _"ein kleines Pause"_ sure?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oops, Pause ist die... ich lerne immer etwas neues :-)